# Notepad++ syntax highlighter bug - how to fix and/or report

Tags: syntax-highlighting, notepad++

I am trying out Notepad++ and have encountered an error with the syntax highlighter within minutes of using it.  In JavaScript, a comment starting with // is handled correctly, but not /// (it shouldn't matter what follows the first 2 slashes, so what is wrong with another / ?).  This does not appear to be a problem with PHP.

A few of questions:
1) Anyone know how to fix this?
2) Is Notepad++ syntax highlighting reliable (I know this could be a matter of opinion).
3) Where can I report a bug? (I looked at their forum but I am spending more time figuring it out than the time it took to find the bug.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a bug. You can check out [What does the three slashes in javascript do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423469/what-does-the-three-slashes-in-javascript-do) to see. I wasn't sure what it did either but apparently some doc generators use /// to annotate docstrings which is why its coloured differently.

Cheers